# Android Inception (A thread within a thread)

Tags: android, multithreading, timertask

I have one function which queries a network server with a few "ping pongs" back and forth, and have written a custom handler to handle the message communication between my main UI thread and the communication thread (I was using AsyncTask for this, but as the program got more complex, I have decided to remove the communication code to its own class outside of the main activity).

Triggering a single instance of this thread communication from onCreate works perfectly, no problem.
I want this query to run on a regular timed basis -- in the background -- for the entire time the app is in use, so I've set up another thread called pollTimer, which I'm trying to use to call the OTHER thread at a regularly scheduled basis.
Obviously, it's crashing, or I wouldn't be posting this.

Is there a way to get a thread within a thread?  Or put differently, trigger a thread from another thread?

```
Timer pollTimer = new Timer();
private void startPollTimer(){
    pollTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG,"timer dinged");
//if the following is commented out, this "dings" every 6 seconds.
//if its not commented out, it crashes
            threadedPoll();
        }
    }, 3120, 6000);
}
private void threadedPoll() {
    testThread(asciiQueries,WorkerThreadRunnable.typeLogin);        
}
```

edit:  it would probably help to include the "testThread" function, which works by itself when called from onCreate, but does not make it when called from the Timer.
"WorkerThreadRunnable" is the massive chunk of code in its own class that has replaced the mess of having AsyncTask handle it inside the main activity.

```
private Handler runStatHandler = null;
Thread workerThread = null;

private void testThread(String[] threadCommands, int commandType){
    if(runStatHandler == null){
        runStatHandler = new ReportStatusHandler(this);
        if(commandType == WorkerThreadRunnable.typeLogin){
            workerThread = new Thread(new WorkerThreadRunnable(runStatHandler,threadCommands, WorkerThreadRunnable.typeLogin));
        }
        workerThread.start();
        return;
    }

    //thread is already there
    if(workerThread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED){
        Log.d(TAG,"thread is new or alive, but not terminated");
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "thread is likely deaad, starting now");
        //there's no way to resurrect a dead thread
        workerThread = new Thread(new WorkerThreadRunnable(runStatHandler));
        workerThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be well on the way already - the nice thing about handlers, though, is that they aren't limited to the UI thread - so if you have a Handler declared by one thread, you can set it up to take asynchronous instructions from another thread

```
mWorkerThread = new WorkerThread()

private class WorkerThread extends Thread {
  private Handler mHandler;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    mHandler = new Handler(); // we do this here to ensure that 
                              // the handler runs on this thread
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // do stuff asynchronously
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps... if I'm totally off base on your problem let me know

Comment: Thanks @JRaymond, The problem I'm having is actually a crash related to "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" with the timerTask.
The very second that threadedPoll() is called from within the Timer, the above is triggered.
If I totally skip the timer, and just run "testThread(asciiQueries,WorkerThreadRunnable.typeLogin)" in the onCreate, THAT custom runnable/handler combination works.  It's being called by the Timer that's killing it

Comment: @Octoth0rpe Ah ok... I think its because your timer thread is the one trying to declare the Handler - which isn't allowed b/c it's not a thread set up for handlers.  Whatever thread invokes the constructor of a handler is the thread the handler is tied to. so if you can find a way to invoke that constructor in the worker thread instead, or roll your own timer thread...

Answer (score 0):

Wots wrong with a sleep() loop?  Why do you have pagefuls of complex, dodgy code when you could just loop in one thread?

Comment: Wot pagefuls of dodgy code?  Trust me, what this app is doing is COMPLICATED.  What you're seeing here is barely scratching the surface of complexity.  (Which is why I have completely moved away from AsyncTask, I need to access the same function from various different activities, and AsyncTask would be getting ugly and difficult to maintain).
I also need to have a custom Handler, due to all the ASCII communication going back and forth.